# Adding values to an object that extends parcelable - Android

Tags: java, android, generics, parcelable

I am trying to implement this [search box](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview) to my project. 
I need to create a list which includes all the suggestions when the user type some text in the text area but I am stuck.

The list I need to create has this form:

```
List<? extends SearchSuggestion>
```

and SearchSuggestion is an interface which extends Parcelable :

```
import android.os.Parcelable;

public interface SearchSuggestion extends Parcelable{
    String getBody();
}
```

I guess I have to create a class which implements SearchSuggestion and put some values there?

Something like this?

```
public class MyClass implements SearchSuggestion {
    public String mystring;

     public MyClass(String text){
         this.mystring = text;
     }
}
```

I really don't have any idea how to proceed with this problem. 
I don't know what else to post here to help you help me, so if you need anything just tell me.

Comment: so what have you tried so far? have you reviewed the code from github you have mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you implement `SearchSuggestion` it gives you the method `String getBody();`

Therefore your object would look like this:

```
public class MyClass implements SearchSuggestion {
    private final String myString;

     public MyClass(String text){
         this.myString = text;
     }

     @Override
     public String getBody() {
          return myString;
     }
}
```

Also your list does not need a wildcard (`?`) it can just be:

```
 List<SearchSuggestion>
```

All of this is explained in the ReadMe of the repo you linked:

https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/blob/master/README.md

it has a demo that does what you are looking for:

https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/blob/ef70366635e19ba1c1337c7df7b2941f8856f756/sample/src/main/java/com/arlib/floatingsearchviewdemo/data/ColorSuggestion.java

&

https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/blob/ef70366635e19ba1c1337c7df7b2941f8856f756/sample/src/main/java/com/arlib/floatingsearchviewdemo/data/DataHelper.java#L69

&

https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/blob/957d726ce0ac31c5db9ae0b55bf29878fa6aafb7/sample/src/main/java/com/arlib/floatingsearchviewdemo/fragment/ScrollingSearchExampleFragment.java#L144

Showing that you add your suggestions like this:

```
 searchView.swapSuggestions(yourListOfSuggestions);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort.